# Show bounding area in Barcode scanner

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement barcode scanning feature in my app (swift) and I've found a project in github that does it great with AVFoundation. Now, I would like to know how could I show bounding area. I've not found any example in swift.

https://github.com/mhassanpur/tutorial-ios-barcode-scanner

**EDIT**
I add the following lines after capturePReviewLayer create in `initializeScanner` and it worked but the layer is black and not clearcolor with red border. Any idea?

```
let rectangle: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2 - 30, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 60))
UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
rectangle.fill()
UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
rectangle.lineWidth = 1
rectangle.stroke()

let circleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
circleLayer.path = rectangle.CGPath
capturePreviewLayer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a box that appears on the camera or one that highlights the barcode once it has been found, [like this](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation)?

Answer (score 0):

I add the following lines after capturePReviewLayer create in `initializeScanner` and it worked perfectly!

```
        let rectangle: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2 - 30, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 60))
        UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
        rectangle.fill()
        UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
        rectangle.lineWidth = 1
        rectangle.stroke()

        let boundingLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
        boundingLayer.path = rectangle.CGPath
        boundingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        boundingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        capturePreviewLayer.addSublayer(boundingLayer)
```